# Create a frame border using dashes and lines C++ around output that came from user input?

Tags: c++

The lecturer asked me to write a code for the Personal CV file to ask the user to input the information and print it with appropriate output. I finished it, I can provide you full detail below.

Now the second task is **creating a border around all the output text as shown in the picture below**. I tried so many ways, I couldn't have any ideas how to do it, and I searched last night over the Internet but was unlucky with no success.

What the lecturer askes me only the border, not content:

[image]

What I have done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    int main() 
    {......
        ofstream MyFile(CVname);
        
          MyFile << "\t\t\t\tResume\n----------------------Personal information----------------------\n";
        
          MyFile << "Name: " << name << "\n";
          MyFile << "Phone: " << phone << "\n";
          MyFile << "Email Address: " << email << "\n";
          MyFile << "Nationality: " << nationality << "\n";  
          MyFile << "Gender: " << gender << "\n";
          MyFile << "Birth Date: " << birthdate << "\n";
          MyFile << "Location: " << location << "\n";
          MyFile << "\n----------------------------Education-----------------------------\n";
          MyFile << education;
          MyFile << "\n----------------------------Experience---------------------------\n" << experience << "\n";
          MyFile << experience;
          MyFile << "\n----------------------------Languages----------------------------\n";
          MyFile << languages;
          MyFile << "\n-------------------------------Skills-------------------------------\n" << skills << "\n";
        
          MyFile.close();
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: how to create the border around all output equally

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the pipe character `|`?

Comment: You could brute force it. Create a `std::vector<std::string> paper(height, std::string(80, ' '));` then just "paint" on that paper. `paper[0][0] = '+'; paper[1][0] = '|';` etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know it's our job to play teacher. But there's a fairly chunky amount going on there that I doubt the OP will have covered (vectors, templates, constructors etc...).

Comment: The left `|` will always be at the very left, for the right one to be aligned: 1) You need a monospaced font. 2) Count how many characters your line has, then add the remaining needed spaces until you reach the desired width and finally print the right `|`

Comment: @George Perhaps. OP will have to tell us if what we propose isn't covered yet so we can adapt our responses.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, unfortunately, we didn't cover vector, template, and constructors and we will not study it because it's only this course we study C++ and we will not study it again

Comment: @SamAnwar I see. Have you studied I/O manipulators, like `std::setw` and `std::setfill`? Have you learnt about `std::string`? Either of those could also help to create the page as you want it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No sir, we havn't studied those too, only so basic and it's been only 4 lectures we studied C++

Comment: Ok, `char` arrays (C strings)? Do you know how to get the length of a C string using `std::strlen`? `for` loops?

Comment: @TedLyngmo You gave me an Idea about this question, thank you I managed to solve it see the answer please

Comment: @SamAnwar Great! Just a minor detail: When you do `int size = 3; string titles [size] = { ...` you are creating a _Variable Length Array_ which isn't part of standard C++ (but is available as an extension in some compilers). If you instead make it `constexpr int size = 3;` (or in this case `const int size = 3;` is enough)  it's however fine according to the standard.

Comment: Btw, you _do_ have studied `std::string`. That's what you are using in your program. It's the `using namespace std;` that hides that fact. I suggest that you don't do `using namespace std;` and write `std::string` instead of `string`. It makes programs clearer and removes a lot of potential problems with name clashes etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thank you very much, I will definitely do that in future programs, I also read an article about what you're mentioning now, good to know more about this. again thanks

Comment: @SamAnwar You are welcome! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int size = 3;
        string name="Test Name for example", age="20", gender="Male";
        string titles [size] = {"Name: "+name, "Age: "+age, "Gender: "+gender};
        int rows = 60;
        cout<<" ";
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            cout<<"-";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
            cout<<"|"<<titles[i];
            double length = titles[i].length() ;
            for(int j=0; j<(rows-length);j++){
                cout<<" ";
            }
            cout<<"|"<<endl;
        }
        cout<<" ";
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            cout<<"-";
        }
        return 0;
    }
```